# how can i make svelte-kit ,electron and mongodb work in production mode.?

Tags: mongodb, electron, sveltekit

I'm trying to build a desktop app using svelte-kit and electron and installing mongodb locally.

I was able to put everything together successfully and everything work just fine (in development mode), the problem I have is with the production. When I build the app the ui is showing but anything related to server is not working.

I build the app using the svelte-kit_static_adapter and electron-builder. After I've done some research I've found that :

1: mongodb can't be shipped with electron, and that's okay since I want it to be offline.
2: svelte-kit endpoints will not be working after building the app using the static adapter (and that's my problem) and as far as I know electron can only work with static html (so I'm really confused).

If i'm using the static adapter then my endpoints will not work and I will not be able to work with database, and if i'm using the node adapter then electron will not be able to connect to it.

SO HOW CAN I MAKE SVELTE-KIT ,ELECTRON AND MONGODB WORK IN PRODUCTION MODE.

THANK YOU.